# Installed module via pip, still get ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, pyenv, configparser

I'm trying to use `w3af` to start doing some routine security testing on a webapp that I'm using. [Install instructions](http://w3af.org/download) recommend cloning a git repo, then running the python code and seeing what dependencies are unmet then installing them. My first run yielded:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser
```

OK, no problem, right?

```
$ pip install ConfigParser
Collecting ConfigParser
Downloading configparser-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Installing collected packages: ConfigParser
Successfully installed ConfigParser-5.2.0
```

Mission accomplished, let's try again!

```
$ ./w3af_console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./w3af_console", line 12, in <module>
    from w3af.core.controllers.dependency_check.dependency_check import dependency_check
  File "/Users/westonx/bin/w3af/w3af/core/controllers/dependency_check/dependency_check.py", line 26, in <module>
    from w3af.core.data.db.startup_cfg import StartUpConfig
  File "/Users/westonx/bin/w3af/w3af/core/data/db/startup_cfg.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

Hmmm. Could swear we took care of that. Let's run pip (maybe pip3?) again to be sure?

```
$ pip3 install ConfigParser
Requirement already satisfied: ConfigParser in /Users/westonx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.2.0)
```

Seems good. Let's check to see if the import path includes that directory:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path)); import ConfigParser;"

/Users/westonx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python38.zip
/Users/westonx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8
/Users/westonx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Users/westonx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

So... we know the sys.path includes the directory pip says the module is installed in, but when we import it, python insists it's not there.

configparser-5.2.0.dist-info and configparser.py are indeed in my ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages directory, so it doesn't look like pip telling me something that's not true. But it sure looks like python is.

I'm using pyenv on MacOS 10.14, not sure if that makes a difference. Anyone have ideas of what next steps should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigParser` is a built in library in Python, but its name was [changed to `configparser` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html). It appears like `w3af` is still using Python 2 (I found [this check that actively states it](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/blob/master/w3af/core/controllers/dependency_check/utils.py), but you never even got  that far). So, to run this code, you need to run it with Python 2.

Comment: I might be a bit hesitant of an Attack and Audit Framework that itself uses a language that's been EOL for over a year and a half (and discouraged for way longer) but that might just be me being grumpy.

Comment: You're quite right, Python 2 is one of several iffy indicators. I'll go in search of something more current, happy to hear recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

There are very many (thousands) of `python3` compatibility issues with the `w3af` codebase. The ConfigParser issue is just the first one you hit - the codebase is full of references to outdated / unmaintained libraries, and has no support for python3 byte strings vs. unicode strings (`b""` vs `""`), which are used throughout the codebase.

There is a `w4af` project on Github, where someone has made the effort to port all the `w3af` code to `python3`, but you didn't hear that from me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).